# Java counting system

Tags: java

I am making course work for my univeristy. And I want to make a test about programming. I am new to java and I need help to make a point counting system after you answer the question correctly. My idea is you get one point for every question you answer correctly.

My code:

```
package sandis_iesmins_kursadarbs;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Sandis_iesmins_kursadarbs {

    public static void main(String[] args) {            
        int a; 

        Scanner intScan = new Scanner(System.in);

        String[] jaut = new String[3]; //jaut = is questions in latvian language
        jaut[0] = "Is java a programming language";
        //jaut[1] = "Kas ir prog1"; these are comments
        //jaut[2] = "Kas ir prog2"; these are comments
        System.out.println(jaut[0]);

        String[] atbildes = {"answers", "1)Yes", "2)No", "3)Maybe", "4)Dont know"}; //answer options
        for (String atb: atbildes) {
            System.out.println(atb);
        }
        System.out.println("Insert your answers");
        a = intScan.nextInt();
        //answer is just "yes" and now I want to add 1 point to my score. How can I do this?
    }

}
```

Does anyboy have an idea for making that kind of counting system. FYI I will have 10 approximately questions.

Comment: Some remarks on your code: variable names are written in camelCase notation and class names are writte in CamelCase notation (first letter is always in uppercase letter). Furthermore, you should not mix languages with your variable names (`intScan` and `jaut`...).

Answer (score 0):

You can keep a variable which will keep track of the score.

```
int score = 0;

/*
Ask your question here
*/

if(/*Correct answer*/)
    score++; // increment score
```

---

Please go through a basic Java tutorial. One is found [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly:

Put a integer called e.g. "counter":

```
int counter = 0;
```

Each time you want add something do:

```
counter++;
```

In the program:

```
  package sandis_iesmins_kursadarbs;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Sandis_iesmins_kursadarbs {

    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        int counter = 0; //New counter
        int a; 

        Scanner intscan = new Scanner(System.in);

        String [] jaut = new String[3]; //jaut = is questions in latvian language
        jaut[0] = "Is java a programming language";
        //jaut[1] = "Kas ir prog1"; these are comments
        //jaut[2] = "Kas ir prog2"; these are comments
        System.out.println(jaut[0]);

        String[] atbildes = {"answers", "1)Yes", "2)No", "3)Maybe", "4)Dont know"}; //answer options
        for(String atb: atbildes){
            System.out.println(atb);
        }
        System.out.println("Insert your answers");
        a=intscan.nextInt();
       counter++; //Add a new point
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `counters`. Create an `int`variable called 'score', and increase it one point if the answer is correct. Here's an example:

```
package sandis_iesmins_kursadarbs;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Sandis_iesmins_kursadarbs {
public static void main(String[] args) {            
    int a;
    int score = 0; 

    Scanner intscan = new Scanner(System.in);

    String [] jaut = new String[3]; //jaut = is questions in latvian language
    jaut[0] = "Is java a programming language";
    //jaut[1] = "Kas ir prog1"; these are comments
    //jaut[2] = "Kas ir prog2"; these are comments
    System.out.println(jaut[0]);

    String[] atbildes = {"answers", "1)Yes", "2)No", "3)Maybe", "4)Dont know"}; //answer options
    for(String atb: atbildes){
        System.out.println(atb);
    }
    System.out.println("Insert your answers");
    a=intscan.nextInt();
    //let's imagine that the correct answer is "Yes".
    if(a == 1){
       score++;
    }


}
```

Btw, if you want to make a system that punish you for wrong answers, you can do something like this:

```
package sandis_iesmins_kursadarbs;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Sandis_iesmins_kursadarbs {

public static void main(String[] args) {            
    int a;
    double score = 0.0;

    Scanner intscan = new Scanner(System.in);

    String [] jaut = new String[3]; //jaut = is questions in latvian language
    jaut[0] = "Is java a programming language";
    //jaut[1] = "Kas ir prog1"; these are comments
    //jaut[2] = "Kas ir prog2"; these are comments
    System.out.println(jaut[0]);

    String[] atbildes = {"answers", "1)Yes", "2)No", "3)Maybe", "4)Dont know"}; //answer options
    for(String atb: atbildes){
        System.out.println(atb);
    }
    System.out.println("Insert your answers");
    a=intscan.nextInt();
    //let's imagine that the correct answer is "Yes"
    if(a == 1){
      score++;
    //the system punishes you -0.25 for wrong answer
    }else{
      score -= 0.25;
    }
}


}
```